# Kivy large text inside lable reversed and inserted from buttom to top

Tags: text, utf-8, kivy, label

I have a program in kivy and I want to insert code text from database to label. Although I checked in static text but same result.
The problem is the large text inserted from bottom to top, and we have to read the text from button to top.

This happened just for utf-8 text which is converted from arabic_reshaper.

This is my code:

```
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(l[x][2])
        bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
        lbl=Label(text=bidi_text,font_name='c:/windows/fonts/tahoma.ttf',text_language='fa-IR',text_size=(800,600),base_direction='rtl')
        
        item.add_widget(lbl)                                          
        
        root.add_widget(item)
```

`l[x][2]` is the text content is read from database.

This is sample text:

"زبان سی شارپ، یک زبان برنامه‌نویسی چند الگویی و منظم شده مدل‌های تابعی، امری، عمومی، شیءگرا و جز گرا و در بستر دات نت می‌باشد. این زبان توسط مایکروسافت و جزئی از دات نت به وجود آمد و بعداً استانداردهای ECMA و ISO را نیز دربر گرفت. سی شارپ یکی از ۴۴ زبان برنامه‌نویسی است که توسط زمان اجرای زبان مشترک از چارچوب دات‌نت پشتیبانی و در همه جا به وسیله مایکروسافت ویژوال استودیو شناخته می‌شود.
"

But the result on screen is bottom to top:

[image]

Comment: Still noone knows the answer?